# Magento - installing extensions error

Tags: mysql, magento, logging, pdo, installation

```
a:5:{i:0;s:108:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
Table 'magento.jmmegamenu_store_menugroup' doesn't
exist";i:1;s:4218:"#0
C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110):
Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

This is the log I got in the `/var/report`

So, I'm sorry for the noob question but what am I supposed to do here?

Comment: The table `jmmegamenu_store_menugroup` does not exist in your database

Answer (score 0):

- Just login to phpmyadmin
- Open core_resource table
- Find _setup entry and delete it.
- Delete all other tables of module (if any).
- Now refresh page.

This time table will be created and error will be gone

:)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `sql` setup is not working properly in this module. Try to correct config.xml of this module within `module/etc` folder.

- Check the resourceModel tag
- Check the table name is defined or not.

After following these step, hope it should work.